# Wordpress Shortcode Displays as is on the Page

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I am using a Portfolio Plugin. And it asks me to add the following shortcode in to the page where i want to show the content

```
[nimble-portfolio template="2colmosaic" types="3,4,5" items_per_page="3"]
```

When i do the following

```
$view = get_page_by_title('View');
echo $view->post_content;
```

It displays

```
[nimble-portfolio template="2colmosaic" types="3,4,5" items_per_page="3"]
```

as text when rendered

**Edit**

I tried to do the following

```
echo apply_filter('the_content', $view->post_content);
```

But it doesn't Render the full page now. And stops upto that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this following code and let me know the case then -

```
<?php echo do_shortcode($view->post_content); ?>
```

Comment: it was apply_filters in plural :D

Comment: @HarshaMV lol good to see you found 2 ways of handling the code :)